# ncat on windows: -e option forwards input but does not forward output

Tags: windows, netcat

I start `ncat` (on Windows 10) with

```
ncat -vvlp 1234 -e code.exe
```

and then connect with a second instance of `ncat` to the first instance
(`ncat 127.0.0.1 1234`).

`code.exe` is a C program written by me that can be controlled over stdin.
Everything I send via the second `ncat` gets forwarded to the stdin of `code.exe`. I know this because I can see `code.exe` create a folder after sending the command to do so. But the output is not send back until `code.exe` closes itself.

Why is that — and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution to my problem. I disabled buffering of stdout by using

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

at the start of my C program.